# HTML Hover img and text at the same time

Tags: html, css, image, hover

Need to add a border color on the img and the same color to the text under on hover.

Thank you!

Comment: share some code please

Comment: It is important for you to show us what you tried so that we can analyze your code and help you with it.

Comment: http://imgur.com/tAEenKO something like this when the mouse is on hover.

a gray color when the mouse is out and red color in the border of img and the color of the text when the mouse is on hover

Comment: <div class="prod">

<a href="http://"><img class="size-full wp-image-682 aligncenter" src="http://a.jpg"  /></a>
<h5 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 15px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #727176;"><a href="http://a/">Letters</a></h5>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

> Here we go:

```css
div.prod {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding:20px;
}

div.prod img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.prod img:hover {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin:-2px;
}

div.prod a:hover + h5 a {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div class="prod"> <a href="http://"><img class="size-full wp-image-682 aligncenter" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150"; /></a> <h5 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 15px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #727176;"><a href="a/">Letters</a></h5>; </div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! but.. If I just need to color the image and text when they just go through the image or the text? Because in the example the hover is activated when the mouse passes over the div and in the corners there is no href, only in the text and image. Thank you Goku :D

Comment: so the border and text color should come without passing the mouse too?

Comment: mmm, sorry for my bad englhis. The links are on the img and the h5 but the hover is active when the cursor touch the div and in the corners of the h5 theres is no link.. because the <a> are only in the img and h5 tag

Comment: nice but the color of the img doesnt change when i hover on the text.. its okay man, I thank you very much, if you can not think of anything else, I'll put you as the best answer

Answer (score 0):

Using the `+` selector to select an element *after* an element with the `:hover` pseudo-class:

```css
img:hover {
    border: thick red solid;
}

img:hover + figcaption {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <figcaption>Caption goes here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Same thing, but with HTML structured like yours:

```css
img:hover {
    border: thick solid green;
}

a:hover + h5 a {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="prod">
  <a href="http://">
     <img class="size-full wp-image-682 aligncenter" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  </a>
  <h5 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 15px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #727176;">
    <a href="a/">Letters</a>
  </h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need, you may have to scroll down a bit to see the text.

```css
body{
  height: 300px;
}
.text{
  color: lightgreen;
  display: none;
 
}
img{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}
img:hover{
  border: 3px solid lightgreen;
}

img:hover ~ .text{
  display: unset;
  display: block;
   padding-top: 40px;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="https://s2.postimg.org/kdwhe6pqh/dude_relaxing_simplistic_1280x800_wallpaper_www.jpg" alt="">
  <h3 class="text">An Image</h3>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```css
.prod {

       text-align: center;
}

h5   {
      
      color: #727176;

      text-transform: uppercase;

      margin-top: 15px;
}

a    {

     text-decoration: none;

}

a img {

      border: 3px solid transparent;

}

a:hover img , a:hover + h5 a {

         border : 3px solid red;

}
```

```html
<div class="prod">

  <a href="#" class="x">

     <img class="size-full wp-image-682 aligncenter" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSEYXFYtEKaqcM2_n4o1ppeWTJhzXjhIaooK76ArmSOkl_r1oE2nQCB-12J">

 </a>

  <h5>

      <a href="#">Letters</a>

  </h5>

</div>
```